# Unable to create scheduled event using AWS SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-event-bridge

I have a SAM `template.yaml` like below:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'

Resources:
  GathererFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: main.handler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        GathererDataSchedule:
          Type: Schedule
          Properties:
            Schedule: 'rate(1 minute)'
  GathererBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: gatherer-bucket
```

I run `sam validate` and it comes back fine.

I try to run `sam deploy` and the deployment fails when creating the schedule. Error says:
`ScheduleExpression is not valid. (Service: AmazonCloudWatchEvents; Status Code: 400; error code: ValidationException;`

I've also tried `Schedule: rate('1 minute')` and `Schedule: rate(1 minute)`

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For me this template is deploying fine using the SAM cli.

[image]

May you try to update your SAM cli? And also check if you have permissions to create Eventbridge events?

Comment: I got it working... I don't *know* exactly what it was, but I suspect.... do I need to run `sam build` each time before `sam deploy` even if I'm only changing the template?

Comment: Yes, if you dont you are only deploying the last version of your template where you did the build. Build also "packages" the template